# Force XMLSerializer not to collapse empty tags?

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, internet-explorer-11, xmlserializer

Is it possible via any configuration option to tell JavaScript's `XMLSerializer` not to collapse empty tags into self-closing tags? I'm feeding an xml string into the xml parser then reserializing it after making modifications to the tree, but where I have an explicit closing tag in the input, this is collapsed to a self-closing tag in the output which is causing problems.

Comment: Had so much hope on this question. Same problem here, collapsed textarea (Ajax4JSF) used in outerHTML = "xxxx" is completely messing everything.

Comment: Similar issue while converting XHR response.responseXML object to string using XMLSerializer in IE11. Returns self closed script tags which doesn't renders in IE. Planning to use regex to fix it, anybody has any other solution

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have jquery available and only wanted to go via xmlserialzer way, you can also use **npm package 'xmldom'**.

```
var serializer = require('xmldom').XMLSerializer;
var str = serializer.serializeToString('your node');
```

It takes care of self closing tags(eg. script tags).
[NPM xmldom](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xmldom)
Works fine in IE11.

Comment: You can take reference from below git hub link which uses the xmldom for IE. https://github.com/futurepress/epub.js/blob/v0.3/src/section.js#L96

Answer (score 0):

Well couldn't find anything but since I was using JQuery I used this :

```
$('<div>').append( $(mynode).clone() ).html();
```

instead of

```
new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(mynode);
```

JQuery version didn't go with self-closing tags.

Note : My problem was only with IE11 so I used :

```
if (Object.hasOwnProperty.call(window, "ActiveXObject") && !window.ActiveXObject && window.jQuery) {
  // is IE11 && Jquery
  $('<div>').append( $(newnode).clone() ).html();
} else {
  oldnode.outerHTML = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(newnode);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I face similar problem. To solve it only in root element (Without **xmldom** or **jquery**)- just check whether xmlstring ends with self-closing tag and replace it:

```js
    //let roottagname = 'script'
    ...
    const serializer = new XMLSerializer();
    let xmlStr = serializer.serializeToString(d);
    if (xmlStr.endsWith('/>')) xmlStr = xmlStr.slice(0, -2) + '></' + roottagname + '>';
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using a Regular Expression to remove all self-closing tags from the HTML output:

```
html = htmlWithEmptyTags.replaceAll(/<([^> ]+)( [^>]+)?\/>/g, "<$1$2></$1>")
```